# When joining a query using separate databases, how can I select an identifying field that lets me know which database the row came from?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to compare rows between identical tables (`TestTable`) in two different databases (`MainDB` and `OtherDb`) to look for data differences for certain fields (`Field1` in this example).

The SQL query is dynamically generated as it loops over a set of tables.  Everything works great for identifying differences, but I can't tell which row came from which database.

**SQL Query:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT Field1
FROM (
    SELECT Field1
    FROM (
        SELECT Field1
        FROM [MainDB].[dbo].[TestTable]
        where Field2 = 'company1'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Field1
        FROM [OtherDB].[dbo].[TestTable]
        where Field2 = 'company1'
        ) UnionedTables
    GROUP BY Field1
    HAVING COUNT(*) < 2
    ) results
```

**MainDB.dbo.TestTable:**

```
MainDB.dbo.TestTable
+---------------+----------+
|    Field1     |  Field2  |
+---------------+----------+
| duplicate     | company1 |
| unique maindb | company1 |
| misc data     | company2 |
+---------------+----------+
```

**OtherDB.dbo.TestTable**

```
OtherDB.dbo.TestTable
+----------------+----------+
|     Field1     |  Field2  |
+----------------+----------+
| duplicate      | company1 |
| unique otherdb | company1 |
| misc data      | company2 |
| misc data      | company3 |
| misc data      | company4 |
| misc data2     | company4 |
+----------------+----------+
```

> **Current Output**

```
+----------------+
|     Field1     |
+----------------+
| unique maindb  |
| unique otherdb |
+----------------+
```

> **Desired Output**

```
+----------------+----------+
|     Field1     | Database |
+----------------+----------+
| unique maindb  | MainDB   |
| unique otherdb | OtherDB  |
+----------------+----------+
```

Comment: Just add a column to both queries. 'Database1' as DatabaseName and 'Database2' in the other query.

Comment: I tried this, and it causes the rows to all become distinct and returns everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seem like what you want. Just add the string representing the database origin to the query generation to produce this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Field1, [DB]
FROM (
    SELECT Field1, 'MainDB' as [DB] 
    FROM [MainDB].[dbo].[TestTable]
    where Field2 = 'company1' AND Field1 NOT IN (SELECT Field1 FROM [OtherDB].[dbo].[TestTable] where Field2 = 'company1')

    UNION ALL

    SELECT Field1, 'OtherDB' as [DB] 
    FROM [OtherDB].[dbo].[TestTable]
    where Field2 = 'company1' AND Field1 NOT IN (SELECT Field1 FROM [MainDB].[dbo].[TestTable] where Field2 = 'company1')
    ) as Results
```

You cannot use a `Group By` in the query without including the `DB` in the Group clause, which made it only unique by the DB. With this you make each data set unique, then union them, eliminating the need for the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Ah, I knew it could be done but was just not able to think of how to do it.  Thanks! One note, `Database` is a keyword, so I changed it to something else.

Comment: Actually, this makes it no-longer distinct and causes all rows to return.  Any idea what to do?

Comment: Ah i see, the Group BY is causing it to do this. Posting an edit now.

Comment: Seems the outer query is not needed using this approach. You could add a group by to each of the unioned queries. The downside here is that now we are hitting both base tables twice.

Comment: Worked great!  One note, your second select, you have `AND NOT IN` which should be `AND Field1 NOT IN` for anyone looking to this answer.